# How to find object position in the serialized generic list

Tags: c#, serialization, filestream

For I can have direct access to a particular object in a serialized generic list, I need to know position of it from de-serialized stream.

```
private static void Serialze(object obj, FileStream Stream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
        bin.FilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Low;
        bin.Serialize(Stream, obj);
    }
private static object DeSerialize(FileStream Stream)
    {
        if (Stream.Position >= Stream.Length) return null;
        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
        bin.FilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Low;
        object x = bin.Deserialize(Stream);
        return x;
    }
```

Suppose I have a generic list like this:

```
List<MyClass> L1=new List<MyClass>();
```

How can I to find position of L1[10] in my FileStreem, for using it, in DeSerialize method?

Comment: That is simply not a feature that `BinaryFormatter` supports. Of course, even if it did, I would still **strongly** advise against using `BinaryFormatter`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you, Marc for you'r advise. I will research about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format that `BinaryFormatter` uses is not seekable. You cannot extract sub-objects.

Probably, this question is an instance of the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you want to achieve and why you need this. As asked, there is no answer.

Maybe you can make use of a database instead. Or, use Protocol Buffers, which are more flexible.

Comment: I need this because because I need to save a list of object and I thought that de-serialize entire list, every time that I seeking for an object of it, is heavy. is there any way except to save each object separately in a file?

Comment: Many strategies. You could start the file with an "array" of all the offsets in the file where the objects are located. Or, you could use one file per object. Or, you find out whether the performance difference even matters. Probably, you can just deserialize the entire file.